# Attach click events in an IFRAME

Tags: jquery

Basically I have an IFRAME that displays a given page. I am using jQuery to append a number of DIVs within the IFRAME upon load:

```
$('#portal').load(function(){
    $('#portal').contents().find('.callout').append('<div class="overlay">Test</div>');
});
```

(#portal is the IFRAME)

Now I want to attach a click event handler to these new DIVs. I believe since I am creating the DIVs dynamically, I need to use the `on()` function, but I having trouble doing this. I have tried:

```
$('#portal').on('click', '.overlay', function(){
    alert("Test");
});
```

The above two snippets of code are in a JS file that is accessible only on the parent page, i.e. the IFRAME itself does not reference the JS file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `$('#portal').on(..)` to `$('#portal').contents().find('body').on(..)`

```
$('#portal').contents().find('body').on('click', '.overlay', function(){
    alert("Test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the iFrame has a unique name, then try this for a cross-browser solution:

```
$('#portal').load(function(){
    $('<div class="overlay">Test</div>')
        .click(function(){
            alert("Test");
        }).appendTo(window.frames[this.name].document.body));
});
```